# oleDB connection: getting exception querying MDX from C#

Tags: c#, exception, oledb, mdx, adomd.net

Please: I receive following exception when trying to run my code:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object...

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=MSOLAP.4; Data Source=<mysource>; Initial Catalog=Analysis ComponetReport;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var mdxQuery = new StringBuilder();
            mdxQuery.Append("SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[AFR] } ON COLUMNS, [DIM_Component_Basic].[KP Mat Nr].children on ROWS FROM (Select [DIM_Component_Basic].[KP Mat Nr].&[" + partNumber + "] ON COLUMNS FROM [CUB Componenten])");
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(mdxQuery.ToString(), conn))
            {
                //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                //ds.EnforceConstraints = false;
                //ds.Tables.Add();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                try
                {
                    part.PartNumber = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

the error occured at the dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())); part.

Now: I would swear to anything that this same code worked 2 days ago. 
And if I change the oleDB part for Adomd it works now as well.

However I can't use Adomd connection because I don't want to use windows authentification.

Comment: have you looked at the inner exception ?

Comment: afaik, there is no inner exception, the exception is thrown at the main code block. We finally didnt find a solution, so we use Adomd connection instead of OleDb and we have updated the rights.